# rich:fileUpload restrict filesize: maxRequestSize does not work

Tags: jboss, richfaces, jsf-1.2

I am using JBoss EPP 5.2.0 with JSF 1.2_14 and RichFaces 3.3.2.SR1 and org.jboss.portletbridge 2.0.0.FINAL.

I want to restict the filesize of uploaded files.
I have tried following:

xhtml:

```
<rich:fileUpload    id="uploader"
                    fileUploadListener="#{controller.fileUploadlistener}" 
                    immediateUpload="true" 
                    allowFlash="false"
                    maxFilesQuantity="#{controller.uploadsLeft}" 
                    acceptedTypes="pdf,jpg,tif,pgm,pbm,png">
            <a4j:support event="onuploadcomplete" reRender="uploadedFiles" /> 
</rich:fileUpload>
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">
    <display-name>Example</display-name>
<context-param>
            <param-name>org.ajax4jsf.COMPRESS_SCRIPT</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
            <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
            <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
            <param-name>org.ajax4jsf.VIEW_HANDLERS</param-name>
            <param-value>org.jboss.portletbridge.application.FaceletPortletViewHandler</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
            <param-name>org.richfaces.LoadStyleStrategy</param-name>
            <param-value>DEFAULT</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
            <param-name>org.richfaces.LoadScriptStrategy</param-name>
            <param-value>DEFAULT</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
            <param-name>org.ajax4jsf.RESOURCE_URI_PREFIX</param-name>
            <param-value>rfRes</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
            <param-name>org.richfaces.SKIN</param-name>
            <param-value>blueSky</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
            <param-name>facelets.RECREATE_VALUE_EXPRESSION_ON_BUILD_BEFORE_RESTORE</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
            <param-name>javax.portlet.faces.renderPolicy</param-name>
            <param-value>NEVER_DELEGATE</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
            <param-name>org.richfaces.fileUpload.maxRequestSize</param-name>
            <param-value>2000000</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
            <param-name>org.richfaces.fileUpload.createTempFiles</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<filter>
    <display-name>Ajax4jsf Filter</display-name>
    <filter-name>ajax4jsf</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.ajax4jsf.Filter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>createTempFiles</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>maxRequestSize</param-name>
        <param-value>2000000</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ajax4jsf</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
<error-page>
    <exception-type>javax.portlet.PortletException</exception-type>
    <location>/faces/errorpages/error.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
</login-config>
```

Following states that it is a bug: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/PBR-241

If I upload a file it seems that the filter is never called.
The filter is only called on server startup.

Without the restiction of filesize rich:fileUpload is missing a key feature.

Is there a workaround for that?
How can I restrict the filesize?

Is there another existing component which does the job with restriction of filesize?

After some work I have tried to solve it with a portlet-filter:

```
    public class MyResourceFilter implements ResourceFilter {

    public static final String MULTIPART = "multipart/";
    public static final String AJAX4JSF_FILTER = "org.ajax4jsf.Filter";
    public static final String PARAM_MAX_REQUEST_SIZE = "maxRequestSize";

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyResourceFilter.class);

    private int uploadLimit = 0;

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws PortletException {
            String maxRequestSizeParam = config.getInitParameter(PARAM_MAX_REQUEST_SIZE);
            if (maxRequestSizeParam != null) {
            try {
                    uploadLimit = Integer.parseInt(maxRequestSizeParam);
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                    LOGGER.warn("invalid Filter init parameter value in portlet.xml: " + PARAM_MAX_REQUEST_SIZE + " - " + maxRequestSizeParam);
            }
            }
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ResourceRequest resourceRequest, ResourceResponse resourceResponse, FilterChain filterChain) 
            throws IOException, PortletException {
            String resourceKey = resourceRequest.getParameter(PortletResourceBuilder.RFRES);
            if (null == resourceKey) {
            // Handle File Upload
            if (isMultipartContent(resourceRequest)) {
                    String uid = resourceRequest.getParameter(FileUploadConstants.UPLOAD_FILES_ID);
                    ResourceRequestWrapper resourceRequestWrapper = new ResourceRequestWrapper(resourceRequest);
                    String contentLength = resourceRequestWrapper.getHeader("Content-Length");
                    int contentLengthInt = Integer.parseInt(contentLength);
                    if (contentLength != null && uploadLimit > 0
                            && contentLengthInt > uploadLimit) {
                    throw new FileUploadException("Multipart request is larger than allowed size");
                    }
            }
            }
            filterChain.doFilter(resourceRequest, resourceResponse);
    }

    private static boolean isMultipartContent(ResourceRequest request) {
            boolean vReturn = false;
            String contentType = request.getContentType();
            if (contentType == null) {
            vReturn = false;
            } else if (contentType.toLowerCase().startsWith(MULTIPART)) {
            vReturn = true;
            }
            return vReturn;
    }
    }
```

portlet.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>MyResourceFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>my.package.MyResourceFilter</filter-class>
    <lifecycle>RESOURCE_PHASE</lifecycle>
    <init-param>
        <name>maxRequestSize</name>
        <value>2000000</value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```

It would be nice if anybody could review the code. 
Does it look good for you?

Regards

Max